# ERROR: No build artifacts found - Android studio (4.1)

Tags: android, github, gradle, github-for-windows, jitpack

Actually, I'm trying to create a dependency in android and I'm receiving like **No build artifacts found** and this is my gradle screenshot:

[image: This is my gradle] and this is log receiving from jitpack.io
[This is log error](https://jitpack.io/com/github/vermat516/UniversalHelper/1.0.1/build.log)

[image]

Help me to create dependency. I'm using android studio 4.1

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding jcenter() as well in your repositories?

```
allprojects {
  repositories {
     jcenter()
     maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. ./gradlew install
2. update gradle version

Comment: you can try update your release version after the gradle file changed